# Angular.js - How to load different menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I 'm starting jquery migrating an application to angular, but it has made ​​me a bit complex. I need to know if someone could help me as routing and load controllers, when login any user. There are two types of users

- Students
- Teachers

Each has a different menu , which in turn has different html pages. Depending on the role the user to enter then load the specific menu.

Using the jQuery load event , and changed the content which changes within a div . I would like to know how to perform this process with angular .

index.html

```
<html>
  <head> Files ... </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

student-menu.html

```
<div>
  <div>option-1</div>
  <div>option-2</div>
  <div>option-3</div>
  <div>option-N</div>
 </div>
```

students-pages

```
option-1.html
option-2.html
option-3.html
option-N.html
```

teacher-menu.html

```
<div>
  <div>option-1</div>
  <div>option-2</div>
  <div>option-3</div>
  <div>option-N</div>
 </div>
```

teachers-pages

```
option-1.html
option-2.html
option-3.html
option-N.html
```

[image]

Appreciate a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider reading about including `ui-router` in your amazing application and learn about `templateProvider`usage.

As soon as you done with above things all you need is:

1. Create `Service` that will have `getCurrentUserStatus()` that should acquire from loaded data about user his status in your system
2. Depending on status configure your child `views: { 'menu': { ... } }` with

   ```
   //somewhere above
   const TEMP = {
       user: 'path/to/file.tpl.html',
       admin: 'path/to/admin.tpl.html'
   }

   //somewhere in view configuretion
   ...,
   templateProvider (AuthService) {
       return TEMP[AuthService.getCurrentUserStatus()];
   },
   ...
   ```
3. Create all another pages with totally same approach of choosing needed template.

P.S. This allows you to expand list of variable templates unless your imagination will empty :D

P.P.S. Noobs way - lot of `ng-include` with `ng-if` on every view that will be changed depending on viewer.

Comment: `templateProvider` is great functionality to determinate non-static templates

Comment: Thank you for your answer , very clear and concise , I would know that m recomndarias to ajax requests angula.js as using a username and password that must load the corresponding menu .

Comment: Just make sure to acquire that information from back-end only once: at application start and store it in service for any-point access.